# How to merge rows dynamically on status base

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i want to merge rows on **Inside** and **Location** base. I want to check how much time a vehicle stay in specific location. Inside **1** mean vehicle enter in specific location and **0** mean left the specific location. If vehicle enter and left same location on specific date than **TimeLast** will be calculate. for example **HD** and **BP** is the location where vehicles enter and left.

```
select zs.oId,o.Number,z.Id,z.Location,zs.TimeFirst,zs.inside from zs join
z on zs.Id = z.Id join 
o on zs.oId=o.oId
where z.GroupId in (1094,1095,1096) and CONVERT(Date,TimeFirst)='2016/5/29'
order by zs.oId,zs.TimeFirst
```

**Output**

```
oId    Number   Id       Location            TimeFirst               Inside
1639    0664    1        Hd        2016-05-29 05:48                0
1639    0664    2        Kp        2016-05-29 18:46                1
1640    0359    1        Hd        2016-05-29 13:12                0
1640    0359    1        Hd        2016-05-29 13:42                1
1640    0359    1        Hd        2016-05-29 13:46                0
1643    0812    3        Lr        2016-05-29 11:41                0
1644    0806    4        Mn        2016-05-29 06:56                0
1644    0806    5        Bp        2016-05-29 09:54                1
1644    0806    5        Bp        2016-05-29 17:43                0
```

**Expected Output**

```
oId    Number     Id    Location      TimeFirst                TimeLast       
1639    0664      1     Hd        2016-05-29 05:48         
1639    0664      2     Kp        2016-05-29 18:46         
1640    0359      1     Hd        2016-05-29 13:12         
1640    0359      1     Hd        2016-05-29 13:42          2016-05-29 13:46    
1643    0812      3     Lr        2016-05-29 11:41         
1644    0806      4     Mn        2016-05-29 06:56         
1644    0806      5     Bp       2016-05-29 09:54           2016-05-29 17:43
```

Comment: Why you tag with two versions of SQL Server? Also, what is the logic by which you expect TimeLast to be filled in? What if you have rows with 3 x status 0 and 3 x status 1 for the same `id` and `name`? Is `Number` functionally dependent on the `id`?

Comment: @trincot question update. i am using Sql Server 12. Inside indicate veh enter in specfic location or left location.

Comment: Please provide the definition of your tables, the primary keys, foreign keys, preferrably the `CREATE TABLE` statements. I don't understand when you want to have a date in the `Timefirst` column and when you want it in the `Timelast` column. Please explain in the question.

Comment: @trincot three tables used in query. "oId' is the foreign key in table ZS and primary key in O table.Id is the primary key in Z and foreign key in ZS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are on Sql Server 2012, you could do this by using window aggregate functions [`lag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [`lead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx), which allow you to compare data with the data in the previous or next record:

```
select   oId, Number, Id, Location, TimeFirst,
         CASE WHEN inside = 1 THEN DepartureTime END DepartureTime
from     (  select   zs.oId, o.Number, z.Id, z.Location, zs.TimeFirst, 
                     zs.inside,
                     lag(zs.inside) over (partition by o.oId, z.Id 
                                          order by zs.TimeFirst) as prev_inside,
                     lead(zs.inside) over (partition by o.oId, z.Id
                                           order by zs.TimeFirst) as next_inside,
                     lead(zs.TimeFirst) over (partition by o.oId, z.Id
                                              order by zs.TimeFirst) as DepartureTime
            from     zs 
            join     z on zs.Id = z.Id 
            join     o on zs.oId=o.oId
            where    z.GroupId in (1094,1095,1096) 
            and      CONVERT(Date,TimeFirst)='2016/5/29' 
         ) as base
where    (inside = 1 or coalesce(prev_inside,0) = 0)
order by oId, TimeFirst
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe9bb/6)

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful for you:

```
select  zs.old,o.Number,z.Id,z.Name,zs.Timefirst, (select case when  zs.timefirst  in (select max(Timefirst) from zs group by zs.old ,zs.id) then zs.timefirst else '' end ) as TimeLast from zs join z on zs.Id = z.Id join o on zs.old=o.old order by zs.old,zs.Timefirst
```